# Nested json reading

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a problem with read the following json.

```
{
    "Message":"The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState":{
        "model.ConfirmPassword":["The password and confirmation password do not match.","The password and confirmation password do not match."]
    }
}
```

I am trying the following(result is not empty and have all neded values)

```
function(result)
        {
        var test=result.responseText;
        var test1=test.Message;
        var test2=test[0];
        var test3=test["Message"];      
        }
```

First test has all json text but i need only Message and later others 
Please help because i do not know what i 've made wrong with read Message info

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` to turn your JSON data into an object before you can access it in your code. So something like this would work:

```
function(result)
    {
    var test=JSON.parse(result.responseText);
    var test1=test.Message;
    // Or you could use
    var test2=test["Message"];      
    }
```